# How to connect a UI5 application to an approuter endpoint?

Tags: sapui5, cloud-foundry

I want to know if it's possible to connect a ui5 application deployed on cloudfoundry to an approuter deployed on the same space inorder to consume an odata service? and if it's possible how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**.
You can simply create the routes in your app router:

1. A route for the odata service which is used by the UI5 application.
2. A route which points to your UI5 application.

Your manifest should look something like:

```js
-- -
applications:
  -name: your_app_name
path: .
buildpack: nodejs_buildpack
memory: 256 M
env:
  TENANT_HOST_PATTERN: "^(.*)-app-router-hostname.cfapps.sap.hana.ondemand.com"
destinations: > [{
    "name": "odata-service",
    "url": "odata_service-deployed.cfapps.sap.hana.ondemand.com",
    "forwardAuthToken": true
  },
  {
    "name": "your-ui5-app-name",
    "url": "ui5-app-deployed.cfapps.sap.hana.ondemand.com"
  }
]
```